# SQL query from Oracle SQL to T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, migration

I have a subquery which is used for an Oracle database, but I want to use an equivalent query for a SQL Server database.

I didn't figure out how to migrate the `TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE` part and also didn't know how to handle the thing with *rownums* in T-SQL.

Is it even possible to migrate this query?

```
SELECT 0 run_id,
      0 tran_id,
      0 sort_id,
      ' ' tran_type,
          10 prod_id,
          72 type_id,
          1 value,
          TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2016-03-18 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') + rownum -1, 'YYYY.MM.DD') || to_char(sw.end_time, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') event_publication,
          EXTRACT (YEAR
                   FROM (TO_DATE('2016-03-18 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') + rownum -1)) y,
                  EXTRACT (MONTH
                           FROM (TO_DATE('2016-03-18 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') + rownum -1)) mo,
                          EXTRACT (DAY
                                   FROM (TO_DATE('2016-03-18 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') + rownum -1)) d,
                                  to_number(to_char (sw.end_time, 'HH24')) h,
                                  to_number(to_char (sw.end_time, 'MI')) mi,
                                  to_number(to_char (sw.end_time, 'SS')) s,
                                  0 ms
FROM all_objects ao,
    settlement_win sw,
    prod_def pd
WHERE pd.prod_id = 10
 AND sw.country = pd.country
 AND sw.commodity = pd.commodity
 AND rownum <= TO_DATE('2016-03-18 23:59:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') -TO_DATE('2016-03-18 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')+1
```

Comment: It's probably possible, yes. `To_Date` and `To_Char` can be translated to `convert`, `rownum` can be `row_number() over(order by...)`.

Comment: To be successful you need to understand what this statement does. Once you know that, I suggest you break this into pieces that you can accomplish. You shouldn't just blindly replace oracle functions with tsql functions. Those old-style joins in the from clause should be your first improvement. Rownum will require some work give the obscure usage in the where clause.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes I thought of convert as well for `To_Date` and `To_Char` but dont know a solution for `to_timestamp`

Comment: @SMor I am kind of new to SQL but noticed that this is somehow out of date code, I will follow your idea of breaking it into pieces

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to address is the use of rownum which has no direct equivalent in TSQL but we can mimic it, and for this particular query you need to recognize that the table `ALL_OBJECTS` is only being used to produce a number of rows. It has no other purpose to the query.

In TSQL we can generate rows using a CTE and there are many many variants of this, but for here I suggest:

```
;WITH
  cteDigits AS (
      SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
      )
, cteTally AS (
      SELECT 
              d1s.digit 
            + d10s.digit * 10
            + d100s.digit * 100  /* add more like this as needed */
         -- + d1000s.digit * 1000  /* add more like this as needed */
            + 1 AS rownum
      FROM cteDigits d1s
      CROSS JOIN cteDigits d10s
      CROSS JOIN cteDigits d100s /* add more like this as needed */
    --CROSS JOIN cteDigits d1000s /* add more like this as needed */
      )
```

This will quickly spin-up 1000 rows as is and can be extended to produce many more rows by adding more cross joins. Note this returns a column called rownum which starts at 1 thus mimicking the Oracle rownum.

So next you can just add some of the remaining query, like this:

```
SELECT
      0 run_id
    , 0 tran_id
    , 0 sort_id
    , ' ' tran_type
    , 10 prod_id
    , 72 type_id
    , 1 value
    , convert(varchar, dateadd(day, rownum - 1,'20160318'),121) event_publication

    -- several missing rows here

    , 0 ms
FOM cteTally
INNER JOIN settlement_win sw
INNER JOIN prod_def pd ON sw.country = pd.country AND sw.commodity = pd.commodity
WHERE pd.prod_id = 10
    AND rownum <= datediff(day,'20160318','20160318') + 1
```

Note that you really do not need a to_timestamp() equivalent you just need the ability to output date and time to the maximum precision of your data which appears to be to the level of seconds.

To progress further (I think) requires an understanding of the data held in the column `sw.end_time`. If this can be converted to the **mssql datetime data type** then it is just a matter of adding a number of days to that value to arrive at the `event_publication` and similarly if `sw.end_time` is converted to a datetime data type then use `date_part()` to get the hours, minutes and seconds from that column. e.g.

```
, DATEADD(day,rownum-1,CONVERT(datetime, sw.end_time)) AS event_publication
```

also, if such a calculation works then it would be possible to use an `apply operator` to simplify the overall query, something like this

```
;WITH
  cteDigits AS (
      SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
      )
, cteTally AS (
      SELECT 
              d1s.digit 
            + d10s.digit * 10
            + d100s.digit * 100  /* add more like this as needed */
         -- + d1000s.digit * 1000  /* add more like this as needed */
            + 1 AS rownum
      FROM cteDigits d1s
      CROSS JOIN cteDigits d10s
      CROSS JOIN cteDigits d100s /* add more like this as needed */
    --CROSS JOIN cteDigits d1000s /* add more like this as needed */
      )
SELECT
      0 run_id
    , 0 tran_id
    , 0 sort_id
    , ' ' tran_type
    , 10 prod_id
    , 72 type_id
    , 1 value
    , convert(varchar(23), CA.Event_publication, 121) Event_publication
    , datepart(day,CA.Event_publication) dd
    , datepart(month,CA.Event_publication) mm
    , datepart(year,CA.Event_publication) yyyy
    , datepart(hour,CA.Event_publication) hh24
    , datepart(minute,CA.Event_publication) mi
    , datepart(second,CA.Event_publication) ss
    , 0 ms
FOM cteTally
INNER JOIN settlement_win sw
INNER JOIN prod_def pd ON sw.country = pd.country AND sw.commodity = pd.commodity
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT DATEADD(day,rownum-1,CONVERT(datetime, sw.end_time)) AS event_publication ) CA
WHERE pd.prod_id = 10
    AND rownum <= datediff(day,'20160318','20160318') + 1
```

NB: IT may be necessary to include this `datediff(day,'19000101,'20160318')`    (which equals 42445) into the calculation of the event_date e.g.

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,42445 + (rownum-1),CONVERT(datetime, sw.end_time)) AS event_publication
```

One last point is that you could use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` if you really do need a greater degree of time precision but there is no easily apparent requirement for that.

Comment: @Mad_Scientist have you been able to convert your query?